# How to input data into different objects in the same database through forms on same html page?

Tags: python, django

The html page consists if two forms of similar type and refers to same database.
The form should take input details of a family of two. However after inputting and submitting the form, the older written objects in the database are erased and overwritten by the newly created objects. I want the objects to be created seperately.

This is my index.html

```
<h1>Fill the form below</h1>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Enter name</h1>
    {{ form.name }}<br><br>
    <h1>Enter age</h1>
    {{ form.age }}<br><br>
    <h1>Enter phone number</h1>
    {{ form.phone }}<br><br>

    <h1>Enter name</h1>
    {{ form.name }}<br><br>
    <h1>Enter age</h1>
    {{ form.age }}<br><br>
    <h1>Enter phone number</h1>
    {{ form.phone }}<br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit file1"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What are we supposed to do with just that template? You at least need to show us the view code responsible for creating the objects, the form class, and probably the model.

Comment: You want to look into something called [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/), which is what Django provides for you to work with multiple forms on the same page, specifically with creating multiple instances of the same object type. Feel free to share some of your view/form initialization code, and we can provide more details to help you achieve your goal.